# View to Edit Mode *with a Wizard at the end*

Tags: edit, view, bulk

I am working on a web app designed for accountants/agents with multiple companies to take care of. One of the main flows the user does is to enter a company details to modify one or multiple sections. Right now they have a "make changes" button that transforms everything in an edit mode (one edit can consist in one or multiple steps *wizard* - now they are presented in modals, we'd like to get rid of them and show the edits as extensions in page). After you complete the edits, you also have to get through a stepper where you sign and confirm changes because this will be also sent as a document to the client. Now, in the wireframes, the stepper has been transformed in a one page questionare that appears after the user would press the "Save Changes" CTA, as a substitute to the previous info. If other view would fit better with an upcoming solution, this can be changed as well.

Current goals:

1. I'd like to make an edit per section option available (right now is only bulk editing) but how can we make that possible without going through that confirmation wizard over and over again as you modify sections. Also, the mass editing, meaning the "make changes" CTA should be out in this case, because when entering the page the user might be confused when seeing also the button and the edit icons for each section on the same time.
2. Does the "Edit per section" option deviates us from a simpler solution?
3. How can I develop a better solution for the user to complete the final wizzard (4 steps) where he just completes data, review the document and the email that he needs to sent to the client (those are templates usually - only the changes are different) in order to save time, besides the already find solution written above?
4. How can the whole editing experience be improved? The first slightly improvement was getting rid of the CTA and transforming it into a toggle that transforms the page from a view mode into an edit mode, but it doesn't necessarily save time or clicks, it just makes the behavior more intuitive.

We've been researching a lot, but I think some advice in this case would be more then welcomed! Thanks!